# Excel VBA debugging method

Tags: vba, excel

i currently have a form with a textbox and a button. you can enter any number in the textbox and when you hit the button it will show the number on a message box, but if there is an error, a message will pop up and you can click the debug button to see which line gave an error. This will be for the code:

```
On Error GoTo 0:
```

But if i replace the 0 with "error:", it will take me to a new subroutine that will send me an email regarding the issue but it will not highlight the line which gave me an error when i hit the debug button.

Is there a way i can send myself an email AND when i hit the debug button it will highlight the error line?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'on error goto error:
On Error GoTo 0:
    Dim word As Double
    word = TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox word
    Exit Sub

error:
    Call error()
End Sub


Sub error()

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "error"

        With OutMail
            .To = "blahblah@hotmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "error"
            .Body = strbody
            .Send
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

    Debug.Assert (Err.Number & Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below pattern calls `error()` then breaks in the IDE on the line that caused the error:

```
Sub Foo()
On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER

    Dim i As Long
    i = i / 0

Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLER:
     Call error()
     On Error GoTo 0
     Resume
End Sub
```